# .htaccess redirect to https except on one page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to get the following things done with my .htaccess:

1. Non www to www
2. http to https except for page `/my/smaple/page`
3. Execute index.php in case the filename is not a file or directory

This is how it looks at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my/sample/page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If I try to access `http://www.mydomain.tld/my/smaple/page`, I am getting redirected to `https://www.mydomain.tld/index.php`. Everything else works though. My .htaccess knowledge is pretty low so please explain me what's wrong.

Comment: By any chance does the request `/my/sample/page` map to a file or directory?

Comment: @Jon Li: `/my/sample/page` is just a route which is created at php runtime from a framework so it is definitely not existent. I use some external resources (mostly images) on this page, that's why I want to use http instead of https. And tbh I don't think the last rule causes this problem, because it's just an internal redirect to index.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `/my/sample/page` gets trapped by the last rule and the rewrite engine then loops. This is what's happening:

1. Request is made to `http://www.example.com/my/sample/page`
2. First rule is skipped, `%{HTTP_HOST}` starts with "www."
3. Second rule is skipped, `%{REQUEST_URI}` starts with `/my/sample/page`
4. Third rule is applied, request isn't for an existing filename or directory. The request URI *is now `/index.php`*.
5. Rewrite engine loops
6. First rule is skipped, `%{HTTP_HOST}` still starts with "www."
7. Second rule **is applied**, `%{REQUEST_URI}` which is now "/index.php", isn't `/my/sample/page`, request gets flagged for redirect to `https://www.exmaple.com/index.php`.
8. Rewrite engine loops
9. Request is flagged for redirect so is sent through the processing pipeline.

Try changing the second rule from:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my/sample/page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/my/sample/page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This way, when the rewrite engine loops, the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable would still be `GET /my/sample/page` and thus the condition still fails.

Comment: Thank you, works perfect. Can you explain me: **5. Rewrite engine loops**. I didn't expect a loop there due to [L]?!

Comment: @nipec The rewrite engine loops through all the rules until the URI stops changing (or if there's specific flags, like a redirect or forbidden). The `L` flag only stops the rewrite engine *in the current iteration*. So with `L`, it stops evaluating all the rules after but it still loops.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution myself.i works fine like this.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8087_check/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8087/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8086_check/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8085_check/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8085/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8084_check/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8084/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8083_check/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8083/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8082_check/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8082/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8081_check/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/websocket_8081/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```